# Adding multiple marks in one line in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to add multiple marks in one line but in different columns? It is a hard limitation in Vim that at most one mark could exist in one line?

Comment: Answer to Q1: Yes. Answer to Q2: No.

Comment: @RSahu, thanks. How can I do this? I tried the normal mark command `m`, and it seems the latter one overwrite previous one in the same line.

Comment: What do you mean by "latter one overwrite previous one"? You mean the previous mark does not work anymore? Certainly that is not the behaviour I am seeing in my vim. You can have multiple marks and move to those marks with the backquote operator.

Comment: @sankoz, you are right. The case I meet is actually I cannot add multiple jump location in the same line to jump list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perfectly set multiple marks on the same line with `ma`, `mb`, etc. but `'a` and `'b` *both* jump to the same line.

Use

```
`a
```

and

```
`b
```

to jump to the exact position — line *and* column — of the mark.